# appending optional elements to an array from json in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have just started getting familiar with JSON. I have a class object that I am initialising by passing in a JSON. This object has an array that may be empty and I need to check it for value. so far I am trying:

```
    init(json: JSON) {
    id = json["id"].string
    type = json["type"].string
    text = json["text"].string
    answer = json["answer"].string
    format = json["format"].string
    answeredBy = []

    if let answeredByjson = json["answeredBy"].array {
        for (_, userDict) in answeredByjson {
           if let userDict = userDict as? [String : Any] {
                answeredBy.append(JSON(User(dictionary: userDict)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the elements in the array are dictionaries that have to be used to initialize another object (User).
the error I am getting is:

> Expression type '[JSON]' is ambiguous without more context.

How can I update my code?

this is my json:

```
    {        
    "answer" : "rachel",
      "answeredBy" : {
       "j1K4WXbOFRXfm3srk9oMtZJ8Iop2" : {
          "email" : "an email",
          "pictureURL" : "a URL",
          "uid" : "j1K4WXbOFRXfm3srk9oMtZJ8Iop2",
          "name" : "a name"
        },
        "vtYlmyerugedizHyOW6TV847Be23" : {
          "email" : "an email",
          "pictureURL" : "a URL",
          "uid" : "vtYlmyerugedizHyOW6TV847Be23",
          "name" : "Rusty Shakleford"
        }
      },
      "format" : "field",
      "id" : "1",
      "type" : "text",
      "text" : "In a foot race, Jerry was neither first nor last. Janet beat Jerry, Jerry beat Pat. Charlie was neither first nor last. Charlie beat Rachel. Pat beat Charlie. Who came in last?"
    }
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error? What is `JSON` (I'm referring the data type in your posted code)?

Comment: @rmaddy probably SwiftyJSON

Comment: sorry, yes. I am using SwiftyJSON

Comment: I recommend using Codable protocol if you are using Swift 4 (Xcode 9 or later). forget about SwiftyJSON. btw you should post your json string

Comment: `answeredBy` in the JSON is not array. Why is it an array in your data model?

Comment: @CodeDifferent answeredBy could have multiple entries representing multiple Users. This JSON only has one entry. answeredBy should be an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Does the JSON sometimes has 1 item in `answeredBy` and sometimes multiple?

Comment: @CodeDifferent correct. answeredBy gets appended with new dictionaries. the JSON is actually a firebase snapshot which I am turning into JSON. The snapshot is a dictionary and I can handle everything fine as a dictionary. I turned it into JSON so I can learn

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Let me phrase it another way: is it always a dictionary in the JSON or can be it an array sometimes?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I updated the code with another User

Answer (score 0):

```
if let answeredByjson = json["answeredBy"].array {
    ...
}
```

produces an array `[JSON]`, but you expect it to produce a dictionary `[String: JSON]`. That is why you receive:

> Expression type '[JSON]' is ambiguous without more context

To produce a dictionary:

```
if let answeredByjson = json["answeredBy"].dictionary {
    ...
}
```

It you don't expect it to produce a dictionary `[String: JSON]` then this line doesn't make sense

```
for (_, userDict) in answeredByjson {
```